# animate view translationY on bottomsheet scroll

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, bottom-sheet

I would like to smoothly animate some views Y position based on the user scrolling a bottom sheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbTx2.jpg

However the animation is slightly jerky.
This is probably because scrolling a bottomsheet gives me a slideOffset at some interval, which is too infrequent to setTranlationY like I'm currently doing.

Is there a better way to do this.

Bottom sheet callback

```
BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheetView, float slideOffset) {
            int offset = (int) (slideOffset * 100);
            if (offset > 0) {
                scrollingHeaderView.animate(offset);
            }
        }
    });
```

scrollingHeaderView

```
public void animate(int offset) {
    position = -(offset / 2);
    arrow.setTranslationY(offset * ANIMATION_RATIO_ARROW);
    detailView.setTranslationY(offset * ANIMATION_RATIO);
}
```

I have tried using ObjectAnimator to create lots of small animations at each step.

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(arrow, "translationY", arrow.getTranslationY(), position * ANIMATION_RATIO_ARROW).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps anyone else.  I got it looking much better.

First i set the ration by pixel * range of values i'd get.  So offset will be 0 -> 100.  Mutliplied by the dp i want the view to move

```
private static int ANIMATION_RANGE = 100;
arrowScale = -(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.arrow_distance) / ANIMATION_RANGE);
containerScale = -(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.detail_distance) / ANIMATION_RANGE);
```

then as the value changes i set this using translationY

```
arrow.setTranslationY(position * arrowScale);
detailView.setTranslationY(position * containerScale);
```

I also needed a reset method, which animate back to the original position

```
public void reset() {
    arrow.animate().setDuration(100).translationY(0);
    detailView.animate().setDuration(100).translationY(0);
}
```